# Laravel 5: override the default view for Registration page

Tags: php, view, laravel-5, registration

I want to change the auth process to use another view template. E.g. instead of `resources/views/auth/register.blade.php` it shall be used `resources/views/register.blade.php`.

But I struggle to find the code where this view is called.

The only place I found was in `app/Services/Register` but only if the validators fails. I need the place when the view is called per default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AuthController, you can overwrite the method `getRegister()` method like this :

```
public function getRegister()
{
   return view('register');
}
```

> Put this code  in your AuthController.

Answer (score 25):

> Laravel 5.6- I am extending **Amarnasan's** answer

In Laravel 5.6, there is no `AuthController.php`. Instead of that, there are 4 different controllers.

- `LoginController.php`
- `RegisterController.php`
- `ForgotPasswordController.php`
- `ResetPasswordController.php`

To override the view of any Auth controller, Just look for the trait that Auth controller is using. Then, Go to that trait file and check which method is returning the default view for the Auth controller.

**To change the default view for login**

add the following in `LoginController.php`

```
public function showLoginForm() {
   return view('auth.m-login');
}
```

**To change the default view for Registration**

add the following in `RegisterController.php`

```
public function showRegistrationForm() {
    return view('auth.m-register');
}
```

**To change the default view for Forgot password**

add the following in `ForgotPasswordController.php`

```
public function showLinkRequestForm(){
    return view('auth.passwords.m-email');
}
```

**To change the default view for Reset password**

add the following in `ResetPasswordController.php`

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null){
    return view('auth.passwords.m-reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the `trait` `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` in file `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` used by the `class` `AuthController` in `\App\Http\Controllers\Auth.php`. Specifically, the register view of your example is called in function `getRegister`

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

in the class AuthController put this :

```
protected $registerView = 'directory.auth.register';
```