# How do i pass roles array which is get from another model to register form in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, authentication

I am new to laravel, i have iniated the default authentication in laravel. but i have modified the users table and it includes role_id which is connected to roles table. Now when registering a user i want people to select their role. The roles should be selected and passed to the register blade. But i do not see a function in the RegisterController which displays the register blade and i can not pass the roles array. Where can i find the class that display the register blade so that i can overrite it.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246869/11219477

you have to add a function to your RegisterController

```
public function showRegistrationForm() {
  //
}
```